# What is required to debug PHP within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, editor

Are any addons required to develop and debug PHP within the Visual Studios 2010 environment?

System Specs:
Windows XP, Apache

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with .Net.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: He's clearly looking for a new IDE

Comment: No I am not lloking for new one. I heard that option is there in VS so for that what action I have to take?

Comment: sounds like ur looking for a new IDE... and ^^^^ is why i edited his question

Comment: PHP Tools for VS http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5/

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to look at VS.PHP for that kind of support - PHP is not natively supported in VS2010

Comment: No, Visual Studio doesn't support PHP without addons. You could setup syntax highlighting quite easily, but no support for debugging or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **PHP Tools for Visual Studio** which adds functionality you need

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5/